# Can I make a print statement run before a module I imported?

Tags: python, python-import

I am a beginner to python and coding in general and I was wondering how I can make a print statement run before a module I imported. I am making a number guessing game and in my main file where I combine all the modules, I have a general function for running all the code together. It would be best if I show my code so you guys will have a better understanding of what I am dealing with:

```
import random
import lvl1
import time

level1 = lvl1.Level_1_activated()

# This is the main file combining everything together to make this game playable

introduction = """
Hello and welcome to NumGuess by Sava. Here is a little bit about the game:
The game works by having 3 levels, each where you must pick a number between a range of
1-10 (level 1), 1-20 (level 2), and 1-50 (level 3).
You are given 5 attempts in the first level, 10 in the second level, and 20 in the final one.
You can also access a hint by typing ‘hint’. You win the game by picking the right number in each level.
You lose the game when you run out of tries. You can get a free bonus with 5 extra tries if you type ‘hlp’. 

"""
def start_game(time, lvl1):
    print(introduction)
    level1
    
start_game(time, lvl1)
```

This is just the code for the main module, I have the code for lvl1 (which is the first level of my 'game'), and I have a class which has all the functions which then take part in the while loop. I will also show that file:

```
import random
import time

# I will fist make variables for the time breaks. S is for short, M is for medium and L is for long

S = 0.2
M = 0.7
L = 1.1

class Level_1_activated():

    def get_name(self):

        # This function simply asks the name of the player

        name = input("Before we start, what is your name? ")

        time.sleep(S)
        print("You said your name was: " + name)

    def try_again(self):

        # This asks the player if they want to try again, and shows the progress of the level
        
        answer = (input("Do you want to try again? "))
        time.sleep(M)

        if answer == "yes":
            print("Alright!, well I am going to guess that you want to play again")
            time.sleep(M)

            print("You have used up: " + str(tries) + " Of your tries. Remember, when you use 5 tries without getting the correct number, the game ends")
            # Return statement for if the player wants to play again 
            return True

        else:
            print("Thank you for playing the game, I hope you have better luck next time")
            # This is the return statement that stops the while loop 
            return False

    def find_rand_num(self, random):

        # This is the core of the level, where the player just chooses numbers between 1 and 10
        time.sleep(S)   

        print("The computer is choosing a random number between 1 and 10... beep beep boop")
        time.sleep(L)

        # The list of numbers for the level that the player is on at the moment
        num_list = [1,10]
        number = random.choice(num_list)

        ques = (input("guess your number, since this is the first level you need to choose a number between 1 and 10  "))
        print(ques)

        if ques == str(number):
            time.sleep(S)
            print("Congratulations! You got the number correct!")

            # Yet another return statement for the while loop
            return "Found"
            
        elif input != number:

            time.sleep(M)
            print("Oops, you got the number wrong")


    # This variable is fairly self-explanatory; it is what controls how many iterations there are in the while loop 
tries = 1

while tries < 6:

    if tries < 2:
        Level_1_activated().get_name()
    
    res = Level_1_activated().find_rand_num(random)
    if res == "Found":
        break

    checker = Level_1_activated().try_again()
    if checker is False:
        break
    
    tries += 1
```

If you go back to this function in the main file:

```
def start_game(time, lvl1):
    print(introduction)
    level1
```

I intentionally put the print statement before the module to make it run first, and I have tried different approaches to this and still can't seem to get a grasp on what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you for taking the time to read the code and I would be very grateful if any of you have a possible solution to this.

Comment: The loop in the lvl1 module that is at top level should be in a function that your main module calls so that you can call it after you print rather than it running at the time when the module is imported.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I am not sure how to write the code. I am still learning python sorry.

Comment: Just writing `level1` has absolutely no effect (other than verifying that you actually have a variable by that name).  You have to actually *do something* with the value - call it if it's a function, invoke a method on it if it's an instance of a class, etc.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are number of thing you can do, one is encapsulate your code into functions that only run when you ask for it

lvl1

```
... #all the previous code    

def run_game(): 
    tries = 1
    while tries < 6:
        ...
        tries += 1
```

you can also make a distinction between being executed directly vs being imported, to do that is simple, you include the following check (usually at the end of the file)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #if true it mean that you're executing this module directly, otherwise it was imported
    #and you include here whatever you want that happens when you execute the module directly but not when is imported, like for example running a game
    run_game()
```

`__name__` is a special variable and python will assigned the value `"__main__"` if executed directly, otherwise it will be the name of the file, like `"lvl1"` for example

And in your main you can import it and do stuff like

```
import lvl1
...

def start_game():
    print(introduction)
    lvl1.run_game()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to remove the print statement indicating the tries, but I can put it anywhere in the loop. You deserved the upvote!